# Can we uninstall Symbian and install Android?

Tags: rom-flashing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I install Android on my non-Android device?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/6849/can-i-install-android-on-my-non-android-device)

I have an Nokia 5233 mobile which has Symbian OS installed. I was wondering whether its possible to remove that Symbian OS and install Android OS? Something like we remove Windows OS and install Linux instead ???

Reason for change?
1) Symbian is giving me lot of problems including viruses, mobile getting hang frequently, applications not working.

2) Want to try Android OS

Answer (score -1):

No because the Android operating system is targeted specifically by the handset manufacturers.

Comment: This is just plain wrong.  The Android project is open source and theoretically can be run on any phone with the correct drivers, as long as it has enough space etc.  In fact, several non-Android phones have had Android installed on them.

Comment: @Matthew Read Just pondering.. wouldn't android require a touch system on the phone anyway?

Comment: @Matthew Read: I suppose I should have written 'No - not easily -..." because I think the O.P. was getting at simply removing the os and replacing it much in the same way Windows can be removed from a PC and a standard distribution installed.