# How can I install Android built from source on a bare device?

Tags: installation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I install Android on my non-Android device?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/6849/can-i-install-android-on-my-non-android-device)

I did look at this 
[Can I install Android on my non-Android device?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/6849/can-i-install-android-on-my-non-android-device)

But my question is a little bit different.

I am trying to install Android on Sony Ericsson Satio (Symbian S60).

Can it be done? If yes, then the question is how?

Are there guides/installers/tools available?

Thanks,
Aseem Chiplonkar

Comment: Aseem  hi and welcome to the site, we've already had a few questions about installing Android on Symbian devices, see these http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/6840/can-we-uninstall-symbian-and-install-android and http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/2889/is-it-possible-to-get-android-on-a-nokia-e65

Comment: Dev questions are off-topic here, thought GAThrawn's answer may help you with that.  The question you linked covers the user perspective.

Answer (score 1):

It won't just be a case of installing from the source, the internals of those phones are different enough from the internals of most Andoird phones that you'll have to port the OS, write hardware drivers and more.

This StackOverflow question [Is it possible to port Android for a Symbian phone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3964606/is-it-posible-to-port-android-for-a-symbian-phone) goes into some of the work that would be needed to port Android to a Symbian device.