# Installing Android on Nokia N96 need help

Tags: rom-flashing, installation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I install Android on my non-Android device?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/6849/can-i-install-android-on-my-non-android-device)

I am using Nokia N96 mobile phone with S60 OS.

Is it possible to load Android OS in my phone.

From where can I download the OS.

Which tool I have to use for OS installation ( tools like PC suit/ OS installer )

After installing the Android OS is it possible to put back the old S60 OS?

Comment: It is **not** possible.

Comment: i doubt an android kernel could interact with a non android compliant device.

Comment: But I heard that people are using Android for nokia phones

Comment: [see this link](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JSfQpgx-b04)

Comment: possible duplicate: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/6840/can-we-uninstall-symbian-and-install-android
http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/6849/can-i-install-android-on-my-non-android-device

Comment: @SarinJacobSunny the original poster confirmed that as a fake.

Comment: @Chahk, sorry I didn't get you, what you ment by fake?

Comment: Fake, as in "not real", a lie.  He most likely is just playing a video, or an animated GIF.